# Java 8 type check for Collectors.groupingBy

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

What do I need to do in order to make the following code type check? The problem is with `s -> s[0]`, where `s` is inferred to be a generic type `T` instead of `String[]`.

```
List<String[]> a = Arrays.asList("a.b","c.b")
                         .stream()
                         .map(s->s.split("\\."))
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
Map<String,List<String>> b = a.stream()
                              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s[0]));
```

The expected result should be a `Map` like this:

```
{a: ["a.b"],
 c: ["c.b"]}
```

Comment: What is your actual input, the `List<String[]>` or the `List<String>` containing `"a.b" and "c.b"`? In the latter case, there is no need to do a two-step operation, in fact, there isn’t even a need to use `split`…

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The problem is with s -> s[0], where s is inferred to be a generic type T instead of String[].

Actually that's not the problem. `s` is correctly inferred as a `String[]`.
However,

```
a.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s[0]));
```

produces a `Map<String,List<String[]>>`, not a `Map<String,List<String>>`. That's the problem.

If you want to join the `String`s of the `String` arrays into a single `String`, you'll need an extra mapping step.

For example :

```
Map<String,List<String>> b = 
    a.stream()
     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s[0],
                                    Collectors.mapping (s -> String.join (".", s), 
                                                        Collectors.toList ())));
```

Output :

```
{a=[a.b], c=[c.b]}
```